# Trying to finish a full basement but footers arent deep enough?

Tags: concrete, concrete-block

I have a full basement that we are wanting to finish, we hired a contractor to come out and estimate and he said we couldn't do it at all because of the slope of the land the footers weren't deep enough to finish the basement.. is there anything I can do? Any suggestions

Comment: Does the basement have a dirt floor ?

Comment: Where are you at and do you have pics?

Comment: The other solution may be to accept that the space won't have a full-height ceiling. The old part of my basement is about 5'9"; not great but when sitting it would make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to [underpin your foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underpinning) with new footers. This is not an easy--or likely cheap fix, however.

Answer (score 1):

Other direction is to raise the house - jack it up far enough to put in another row or two or three of block (if the footers are a consistent amount below the top of the foundation and 8, 16 or 24 more inches is all that's needed.) That can be relatively affordable.

If the footers are not very far below the rim joist on the side where the ground is high (ie, they are a few feet below ground level, but relative to the sloping surface) then you are probably looking at a situation of "not remotely economical to do." It can be done, but costs may be prohibitive.

- You can build a new foundation under the house (with the house jacked
  and blocked up in place.)
- you can build a new foundation beside the house and move it.
- or you can roll the house off to the side and build a new
  foundation where the old one is, then move it back.

The latter two options mean not having to do all the foundation work with the house in the way. Occasionally it must make sense to do, as I've seen all three done, but it certainly should make you take a look at other options for expanding your living space, such as building an addition or a separate freestanding building.